# Try Catch in Swift, Can't figure it out

Tags: swift, try-catch, do-catch

I'm trying to put the following in a do try catch block, but I always end up getting a coding error. Can someone help me?

```
 let here = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30, y: 80, width: 10, height: 10)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            let popTip = PopTip()
            popTip.show(text: "Font Sizes", direction: .down, maxWidth: 200, in: (self.navigationController?.view)! , from: here, duration: 3)
        }
```

Comment: Only APIs which `throw` can be `caught`. Handle the optional properly.

Comment: I get an error at the popTip.Show line. It's because the navigationController is not available because of the dispatch and the user moves to another controller before the async task is executed after 3 seconds of delay. How do I go about handling it then? I'm sorry for being a trouble. I've spent hours trying to figure out. I finally gave up.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have nothing that actually throws an error (i.e. marked with `try`). I can't fully understand what you are saying in your comment, however I believe you might solve this without a `do-catch` clause but with a **`guard-let` statement to check if `self.navigationController.view` is `nil`.** If it's `nil`, just `return` the function.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I'm a self-taught programmer for the most part, but I owe my success to co-programmers on StackOverflow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Always a pleasure to help a self-taught programmer like me!!